# Kryonet server send raw byte array

Tags: tcp, arrays, kryonet

Simple question, is it possible to send a raw byte array packet with Kryonet? The client doesn't use Kryonet and will read the bytes

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kryonet is based on simple tcp communication via NIO along with build-in kryo serialization. Kryonet without kryo serialization is just tcp client/server, nothing more.

Or if you want simple solution, you can just create a wrapper for the entity having one attribute in the form of byte[] and use customer serializer to serialize byte[]. It's the fastest way for some proof of concept etc.